# Moving the img element up the dom for multiple blog posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, business-catalyst

Hi there I would like to do the following:

I am currently using business catalyst as my framework. They have a blog module that gives little no customization, in terms of blog lists. They have a preview tag that previews the the blog posts, and I only went it render the first image that shows up in the post, and nothing else.

By default if I put an image at the top of the blog post, BC will only render only the photo. If I don't put a photo, BC will render half of the blog post - which is stupid. No matter what the circumstance I just want the first photo rendered.

This needs to happen before BC renders the post.

How can I achieve this?

This is before:

```
<div class="blog1"><p>text</p><img src="#"></div>
```

This is after:

```
<div class="blog1"><img src="#"><p>text</p></div>
```

Comment: You want a jquery function to change before to after?

Comment: yes but it must be before the post renders other wise the text will show up

Comment: Hey Kevin, by any chance will you be able to assist me in updating the code to find images that are burried is a ol li. For some reason the :first selection can't find the img, Is there are code that will find any image any where?

Comment: Is there only ever one img as a child? $this.find('img') should find any image that is a child of the blog1 div. You can also do $this.find('img').eq(0) to get the first img found (in case multiple are). There is also $this.first('img'), but I don't know if that deals with nesting. Let me know if any of those work

Comment: http://oneloveallequal.businesscatalyst.com/ Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: What is wrong with it? Should it have more blogs underneath the 4 in the bottom right?

Comment: Notice how it says 15books by... there should be an image there.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint in the function, on page load there isn't an image as a child of that particular div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it truly before it renders is handle it on server side. If you don't have access to that you can put a style rule in your header:

```
<style>
    .blog1{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

and then make a js function to render it the way you want and then display it:

```
(function($, window){
    function moveImages(){
        var $blogs = $('.blog1');

        $blogs.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $img = $this.find('img:first');

            $this.append($img);

        });
    }

    $(window).on('load', moveImages);
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: I updated it to use jQuery .each function. It is more browser friendly. I don't think IE8 supports .forEach

Comment: Also noticed I forgot to wrap window in $()! Added that, window.on will throw an error, it should be $(window).on

Comment: $(function($, window){
    function moveImages(){
        var $blogs = $('.blog1');

        $blogs.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $img = $this.find('img');

            $this.empty()
                .append($img)
                .css('display', 'block');
        });
    }

    $(window).on('load', moveImages);
})(jQuery, window); <-- like this?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to reflect the currently correct code, but yes that looks to be the same!

Comment: Hey I made some changes that seem to work but now the only problem is that it takes forever to load. Any fix for that?

Comment: You can try to listen for $(window).on('DOMContentLoaded') instead of $(window).on('load'). Load waits for all scripts/styles to be parsed and images to be loaded. DOMContentLoaded will fire sooner (as soon as the dom hierarchy is built)